# Компилятор для си под win xp

Tags: c, компиляция, компилятор

Начал изучать язык си, не могли бы вы подсказать какой мне необходимо скачать компилятор для того что бы создавать программы типа "привет мир", Хотел установить Visual Studio  но устанавливать 10 гигов ради мальнекого компилятора не очень хочется.

Comment: Насколько я помню, поддержка именно C (в отличие от C++) у Visual Studio не очень. Так что да, лучше поставить что-то ещё.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам подойдет среда программирования CodeBlocks - в нем есть встроенный компилятор на базе MinGW - [втыкать сюда](http://www.ded32.ru/index/0-7)

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно

Answer (score 1):

[Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers/lunasr2)

[The GNU Compiler Collection](https://gcc.gnu.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Если нужен именно С, то можно попробовать [Pelles C](http://www.pellesc.de/index.php?page=overview&lang=en). Из плюсов:

- удобная IDE
- редактор ресурсов (картинок, иконок, курсоров)
- по заявлению автора, практически полная поддержка C99.
- портабельный (на самом сайте инструкция, как это [делать](http://www.pellesc.de/index.php?page=overview&lang=en)
- и все в одном пакете

Последний раз я им пользовался много лет назад и тогда он был сильно удобнее студии (тогда ещё шестой)